# Is it possible to use Openmp in a "for" loop containing Neon inline assembly?

Tags: android, c, assembly, openmp, neon

My knowledge of openmp is near to none, so I prefer to ask before trying to do something that perhaps does not make sense:

I have some routines for bitmap manipulation ( where the result of each pixel will not depend on the others) writen using inline neon assembly for arm-v7 android devices.

Now I would like to use openmp in order to further accelerate it: divide the bitmap array in 4 (for instance) zones and execute it in paral.lel.

But I don't know if there are limitations regarding:

1. openmp implementation -> is there any limitation in using openmp with
   inline assembly inside the loop?
2. hardware issues -> I don't know if in arm-neon multicore processors, each core has its own neon co-processor and if they can be used at the same time.

The function structure is like this

```
void ProcessBitmapArray( int* wArray, int wWidth, int wHeight, const char* bOptions)
{
  int j;
  for(j=0;j<wHeight;j++){
    asm volatile(
      // neon code here
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That would depend on the contents of the inline assembly. As long it only uses private objects it should work fine. OTOH, if you're modifying global objects in the assembly, things may get dicey.

Comment: Thanks, I am only modifying the array elements passed as the argument, and the regions modified will be independent through the different threads. Regarding "subquestion 2", my concern is to know if in modern big-little architectures, as they are heterogeneous, all the processors involved support neon?

Comment: Even on systems where cores share execution resources (e.g. AMD's recent designs), *the programmer's model* is that each core is independent (at least on mainstream architectures). The necessary logic to keep up the illusion of independence is implemented by the hardware (i.e. one of the cores might stall if the other core is using a shared resource it needs). Even *if* not every ARM-core in your system has its own NEON-unit, to the programmer (even the assembly-programmer), the only evidence of shared resources is reduced performance.

Comment: ok, now it is more clear. Time to upgrade my NDK and start fighting with it. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you even need to write inline assembly? Do you think that you could optimise better than the compiler? If it is about NEON, why not use [intrinsics](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0073a/IHI0073A_arm_neon_intrinsics_ref.pdf) instead. Those look like normal function calls and get expanded into the proper instructions when possible.

Comment: Well, all the neon part is already working long ago and allows me to process real time camera preview for an Android app that is in the market. I just wanted to explore if openmp can give more power to what is already done.